# Why node-sass can't find one of my mixins,the other one works well

Tags: sass, node-sass

I have two mixins like this,

```
@mixin clearfix {
  &::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

@mixin respondphone {
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

and I implemented  the respondphone one like this,

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;

  @include respondphone {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
}
```

But the problem is while I don't get any error for the clearfix one,I,m getting this error for this one ,why?

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "D:/cssmastercourse/natours/sass/base/_base.scss",
  "line": 13,
  "column": 12,
  "message": "no mixin named respondphone",
  "formatted": "Error: no mixin named respondphone\n        on line 13 of sass/base/_base.scss\n        from line 1 of sass/main.scss\n>>   @include respondphone {\r\n   -----------^\n"
}
```

I've imported it correctly to the main file like this,

```
@import "base/base";
@import "base/animations";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/utilities";
@import "abstracts/functions";
@import "abstracts/mixins";
@import "abstracts/variables";
@import "pages/home";
@import "components/button";
@import "components/composition";
@import "components/feature-box";
@import "components/card";
@import "components/story";
@import "components/bg-video";
@import "components/form";
@import "components/popup";
@import "layout/header";
@import "layout/footer";
@import "layout/navigation";
@import "./base/typography";
@import "layout/grid";
```

Comment: The order of your imports is important. If any of the files imported before your mixin use that mixin, it won't be defined